# Metafor package: Cannot use the influence function when model has interactions

Tags: r

My apologies if my question is misplaced, it is possible the question would be more appropriate in Cross-Validated.

I am using the function `influence` of the `metafor` package, that provides various sensitivity to outliers measures (Cook's distance for example). Here's my model and the error provided by `influence`:

```
> resMod2 <- rma(Total$abs_d, Total$vd, mods = ~ Total$log_rayon + Total$log_rayon2 + Total$AssT + Total$AssT2 + Total$ES + Total$AssT2*Total$AssT + Total$log_rayon*Total$AssT2,  method = "REML", data = Total)
> inf <- influence(resMod2)
Error in Xi %*% res$b : non-conformable arguments
```

Now, when my model does not include interactions, I do not have this error.
So, my question: what does this error mean ? Can I do something about it ?

Update: after updating to metafor 1.9-5. I was preparing a subset of my dataset to help find the problem. I realized that I didn't had the error with a subset. Following a set of trials, the error appears when this line of data is included:

```
    > test[103,]
     ES   AssT2 AssT        vd    abs_d log_rayon log_rayon2
103  g Neither   AR 0.2352841 1.185764  1.128558   1.273643e+00
```

Here's a sample from the rest of my data for comparison:

```
    > head(test, n = 20)
        ES    AssT2 AssT          vd      abs_d     log_rayon   log_rayon2
    1  OR  Classic   AR 0.100308141 0.65422508 -6.9077552790 4.771708e+01
    2  OR  Classic   AR 0.133744188 2.83070510 -6.9077552790 4.771708e+01
    3  OR  Classic   AR 0.097268501 2.42278885 -6.9077552790 4.771708e+01
    4  OR  Classic   AR 5.754039740 0.88954233 -6.9077552790 4.771708e+01
    5  OR  Classic   AR 4.641531264 0.74472762 -6.9077552790 4.771708e+01
    6  OR  Classic   AR 1.033477819 0.22271484 -1.0188773206 1.038111e+00
    7  OR  Classic   AR 0.291805502 1.94501000 -6.9077552790 4.771708e+01
    8  OR Contrast   AS 0.091189219 0.03322932  0.0009995003 9.990009e-07
    9  OR Contrast   AS 0.227973048 0.31800789  0.0009995003 9.990009e-07
    10 OR  Classic   AS 0.009118922 0.11226319 -0.5780343735 3.341237e-01
    11 OR  Classic   AR 0.072951375 0.57212362 -1.2006450142 1.441548e+00
    12 OR  Classic   AR 3.139948785 0.60140953 -2.2926347621 5.256174e+00
    13 OR Contrast   AS 3.641489492 0.01651413 -2.2926347621 5.256174e+00
    14 OR  Classic   AS 0.027356766 0.70202373  0.0009995003 9.990009e-07
    15 OR  Classic   AS 0.021277485 0.31418150 -6.9077552790 4.771708e+01
    16 OR  Classic   AR 0.021277485 0.31418150  0.0009995003 9.990009e-07
    17 OR  Classic   AR 0.095739331 0.48683262 -6.9077552790 4.771708e+01
    18  g  Classic   AS 0.036639031 0.32182515 -6.9077552790 4.771708e+01
    19  g Contrast   AS 0.037021684 0.38265986 -6.9077552790 4.771708e+01
    20  g Contrast   AS 0.373049484 0.93066259 -0.5705936364 3.255771e-01
```

Comment: Which version of the `metafor` package are you using? The current version is 1.9-5 and I have a hard time imagining how this error could arise in that version. But without a small reproducible example, I cannot further diagnose where the error is coming from. Aside from this, you really don't need all those `Total$` parts. The entire point of the `data` argument is to avoid stuff like this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the tips for elegant coding ! I'm on 1.9-4, so I will update and check if I still get the error.

Comment: I've update my question, as I still get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your update, I can see now what's going on. Basically, the problem is this: With that row of data included, all of the model coefficients can be estimated. However, when that row of data is removed (which is part of what the `influence()` function is doing -- for example, to compute the deleted residuals), one or more coefficients are not estimable, so they are in essence removed. The multiplication then fails due to incompatible dimensions.

That's a bug. This will be corrected in the next version. I already added this to the development version, which you can install as described here:

http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/installation#development_version

Note that most of the influence diagnostics will be `NA` for that study.